# App Crashing on certain iOS versions

Tags: ios, crash, sprite-kit, version, backwards-compatibility

I've released an app for iPhone. My deployment target is 7.0, base SDk latest. and it work fine on the latest version iphones, but some people are saying it doesnt work on their phone, when I asked what version they are running, they say below 7.1 so something like 7.0.4.
I went on apple documentation, https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/releasenotes/General/iOS71APIDiffs/index.html

the only one that applies to me is SKView.showsPhysics, I only added this during development to test my physics, but i left the code and set the boolean as NO, is this the reason why it crashes on iOS < 7.1 , as it was added after 7.1?

Comment: You need to provide a fully symbolicated crash report and relevant code.

Comment: Yes it is,  showPhysics does not exist on iOS < 7.1 so your app will crash everytime that code is executed

Comment: I understand it could be other things as well, but that is definitely one of them right, I can get the reports because its not my iphones

Comment: Just thought I would add this : If your app is on app store you should get crash reports. If you have hosted your app temporarily on your servers consider using TestFlight which gives you crash reports.

Comment: my app is live on the store, but still no reports says too few reports submitted to be shown

Comment: Just to update, I downloaded the older version of Xcode with 7.0 simulator and copied the 7.0 simulator to my Xcode version, then I ran the app in the 7.0 sim with the error of showPhysics, once i deleted this line, the app ran fine on 7.0 sim. Thanks. Submitted the fixed app last night as an update.